# Proof of submodularity property of influence function in the Independent Cascade Model

Tags: functions, graph-theory

In [this](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/home/kleinber/kdd03-inf.pdf) paper I'm facing difficulty to understand the **Proof of Theorem 2.2** in the **page 4**, specially this sentence - "This is the number of elements in R(v, X) that are not already in the union ∪u∈S R(u, X); it is **at least** as large as the number of elements in R(v, X) that are not in the (bigger) union ∪u∈T R(u, X)".

My problem is with the **at least**. According to my understanding, as S ⊆ T, the number of nodes which are **reachable from v that are not among the nodes reachable from S** should have been **less** than the number of nodes which are **reachable from v that are not among the nodes reachable from T**.

I've come across submodular functions first time in this paper. It'll be great if someone resolves my doubt preferably pictorially with an example.

Comment: Because $T$ is bigger than $S$, it will remove more nodes from those reachable from $v$. For example, take $S$ the empty set. Not nodes are reachable from the empty set, so the number of nodes which are reachable from $v$ that are not among the nodes reachable from $S$ is exactly the number of nodes which are reachable from $v$. If $T$ is non empty, is may remove some nodes, so the number of nodes which are reachable from $v$ that are not among the nodes reachable from $T$ must be lower than the number of nodes which are reachable from $v$